# React Navigation StackNavigator not appearing when used inside another view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm attempting to use a React Navigation StackNavigator for a process that includes a static component at the top of the page and varying components at the bottom.  The code I'm using is:

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator ({
        splash: Splash,
        prompt: Prompt,
        pinCheck: PinCheck
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'splash'
});

export default class Login extends React.Component
{
    constructor (props)
    {
        super (props);

        // code to set up animation state    
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        // code to set up animation
    }

    finish_ (state)
    {
        this.props.navigation.navigate ('main', state);
    }

    render()
    {
        const screen = Dimensions.get('screen');

        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={Global.styles.verticalFill} ref={this.saveContainerRef}>
                <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    <Animated.View style={{opacity:this.state.fade1,alignItems:'center'}} >
                            <Image
                                        style={{width:screen.width * 0.6,height: screen.height*0.55}}
                                        source={imgLogo}
                                        resizeMode='contain'
                                    />
                            <Navigator />
                    </Animated.View>
                </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

When I run this, however, my initial route component is not shown.  It works correctly if I swap `<Navigator/>` to `<Splash/>` however, so the component itself definitely works in this context.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your navigation setup.

> All the routes in the `StackNavigator` must declare a screen
>   as mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation.html)

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator ({
    splash: {
        screen: splash
    },
    prompt: {
        screen: prompt
    },
    pinCheck: {
        screen: pinCheck
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'splash'
})
```